# iOS: Limit CGRectIntersectsRect to one intersection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk, cgrect

I am using the basic CGRectIntersectsRect to detect a collision between sprites as follows:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(staff.frame, imgView.frame)) {
    [self playSound];
}
```

However, since `staff.frame` is moving consistently over the frame of `imgView.frame`, the method `playSound` is fired multiple times - as many times as it takes for the sprites to override each other - causing an unwanted and extreme amount of playback from the `playSound` method.

That being said, is it possible to limit the `CGRectIntersectsRect` method to only allow one collision before breaking the detection?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is declaring a `BOOL` instance variable and use it to only play the sound once per collision. Your code will be something like this:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(staff.frame, imgView.frame)) {
    if (!soundPlayed) {
        soundPlayed = YES;
        [self playSound];
    }
}
else {
    soundPlayed = NO;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.